# Sound Input/Output w/ Mudita24 and Delta 1010LT

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone, input

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (64-bit) with an M-Audio delta 1010LT soundcard. I installed Mudita24 which allowed me to hear system sounds and applications once I turned up the DAC volumes in the analog volume tab.

My problem is this: I cannot seem to get Ubuntu (pulseaudio) to recognise my inputs, I have the ADC faders turned up in mudita24 and I can even see the input volume when I speak into the mic (on monitor inputs tab) but there doesn't seem to be a way to select which input I want to use. In the pulse audio input options I just get a choice of Analog Input or iec958-stereo-input both with the subheading: ICE172[Envy24] PCI Multi-Channel I/O Controller.

I don't know if anyone has experience of this, my mic is going into H/W input 3 in the Delta1010LT, I'm trying to get teamspeak working.

Comment: Okay, so I solved my issues, I'm not sure if this is the "best" way but it works for what I need, flawless pulseaudio for normal desktop operations and a working solution for mumble/teamspeak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I solved my issue, I'm not sure if this is the "best" way but it works for what I need, flawless pulseaudio for normal desktop operations and a working solution for mumble/teamspeak, and it was pretty easy to accomplish thanks to pablomme over at the launchpad.net forums.

I'm a Linux noob and i struggled for days with a jack setup but in the end I couldn't achieve what I wanted that way.

This is more for users who aren't going to use their Delta 1010LT for pro-audio applications (I personally use my windows boot for that atm). If you are looking to use the Delta 1010LT for recording and mixing etc, I'm pretty sure you want a jack setup instead of pulse audio (although you can get both working with the pulseaudio jack sink).

Anyway on with the solution, as I mentioned before Mudita24 is considered the preferred mixer for these cards, so download that from the ubuntu software centre or using the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get mudita24
```

Then open mudita and go to the Analog Volume tab (furthest to the right on mine), and turn up everything! (you can tweak the gains later) I don't know why they are set to zero by default but nothing at all works unless you turn up the Analog Volume sliders. DAC are the outputs (Digital to analog) and ADC are the inputs (Analog to Digital). After you've done this go to the monitor inputs tab and you should be able to see a level when you talk into your mic. Now to get this sound into the pulseaudio.

After much scouring of various websites I found this solution from pablomme:

run "`cat /proc/asound/cards`", and note the card's name in the brackets, e.g. "M1010LT" in my case:

```
 0 [M1010LT ]: ICE1712 - M Audio Delta 1010LT
                      M Audio Delta 1010LT at 0x1140, irq 20
```

Then add the following at the end of `/etc/pulse/default.pa`, replacing M1010LT with whatever you found above:

```
load-module module-alsa-sink sink_name=M1010LT_Analog_Out device=hw:M1010LT channels=10 channel_map=left,right,aux0,aux1,aux2,aux3,aux4,aux5,aux6,aux7
load-module module-alsa-source source_name=M1010LT_Analog_In device=hw:M1010LT channels=12 channel_map=left,right,aux0,aux1,aux2,aux3,aux4,aux5,aux6,aux7,aux8,aux9
```

Also comment out the udev section (~7 lines) starting

```
### Automatically load driver modules depending on ...
```

Then run `pulseaudio --kill && pulseaudio --start`, and you should be done.

The above is from Fedora's bugzilla, https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=507205 , and is apparently a PulseAudio issue. Another possible workaround is in https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=499435 , which involves writing a /etc/asound.conf."

This will make pulseaudio recognise all of the inputs and outputs on the card, after you've done this install the pulseaudio volume control from the ubuntu software centre, or alternatively via the terminal using:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

After you've done this then open up teampseak/mumble (I've actually only tested this with mumble as that ended up being the better VOIP solution), choose pulse audio for the input/output device and then in the pulseaudio volume control go to the recording tab and you should see an entry for your VOIP software (meaning teamspeak or mumble).

Assuming the entry for your VOIP client is there then the default setting should work but I selected the ICE1712[envy24] for both the microphone from and also the mumble speakers echo from.

Next, go to the input devices tab and you should now see all of the inputs for the card. Turn them all down, then uncheck the padlock button so you can move the sliders seperately and just turn up the one you want. Mine had different names but were in the same order as the inputs in mudita24, but it might take some trial and error to find the right one :/

Hopefully now everything should be working, you can tweak the gains from mudita/PulseAudio Volume Control/VOIP to get the best sound quality, but I'd suggest trying everything maxed to begin with (probably not necessary).

I hope this helps some people, that's what worked for me so good luck!